# How to move x-axis labels from the top to the bottom when using facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have next plot:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x=value, y=meanAcc, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(size=0.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE) +
  theme(strip.background=element_rect(color="white", fill="white"),
        axis.title.x =element_blank(),
        axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 2, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0),size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 14),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA,color = "black"),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_text(size=12),
        legend.key=element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(.~variable, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(y=expression(Hourly~Acoustic~activity~(m.s^{-2}))) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))
```

[image]

I would like that the X-axis labels appear in the bottom instead of in the top. How could I change that?

Additionally, I wanted to try another type of line for the X-axis to mark the limits among plots. Some days ago I saw a line that sticks out and marks the boundaries of the plot. So, additionally, does anyone know how to change the type of x-axis line?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the line part of the question. What do you mean with "mark the boundaries of the plot"? Maybe you could add a link to an example

Comment: You dont have grp_1 and so on in your data! This is how the groups are called in my example (look at the data). You need to adapt the code to your data. As you dont need to rename anything you can just comment out the relevant line, see updated answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant options are `strip.position = "bottom"` inside wrap, and `strip.placement = "outside"` inside theme. In addition, if required, you can rename the facets inside wrap. See code below.

[image]

```
d <- read.table(text = 
                  "Grp     Var    Col1  Col2    Col3
                grp_1   8      46.8  50.0   50.6
                grp_1   16     95.6  47.4   48.0
                grp_1   24     45.1  45.6   46.4
                grp_1   32     68.8  44.3   58.2
                grp_1   40     44.6  52.2   44.3
                grp_1   48     86.5  42.2   68.6
                grp_2   40     63.2  95.6   63.0
                grp_2   60     66.7  67.5   65.6
                grp_2   80     69.6  70.7   67.9
                grp_2   100    71.9  73.4   69.3
                grp_2   120    73.8  75.7   48.0
                grp_3   500    51.9  50.0   50.5
                grp_3   1000   65.5  53.0   53.4
                grp_3   5000   61.2  99.0   59.9
                grp_3   10000  80.1  63.0   62.8
                grp_3   30000  25.9  33.8   14.2
                ", header=T
)

library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

d <- setDT(d)
dd <- melt(d, id.vars = c("Grp", "Var"), measure.vars = patterns(col="Col") )

ggplot(dd, aes(Var, value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Grp,
             scales = "free",
             # comment out next line if renaming facets is not necessary
             labeller = as_labeller(c(grp_1 = "Step 1", grp_2 = "Step 2", grp_3 = "Step 3")  ),
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  xlab(NULL) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
```

---

)

Comment: Thanks @desval, it looks like if it was the solution. However, there is an small problem, in the X-axis appear `NA` instead of the name I gave using `labeller = as_labeller()`. I add the updated code and the plot in my post in order you can see it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your data, or part of it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am gonna try it. Furthermore, I found out how to do what I meant about to change the X line aspect. I added some lines in the code as you can see.

Comment: You were right!!! I failed when I used `grp_1` and so forth in my case. I misunderstood that. Now it works great!!!! Thanks a lot. I will update also my post showing the code to change the X-axis line.

Comment: And one doubt if it is possible @desval, can I change the size of this labels?